# Why does flutter doctor not recognize Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

This is the error that I am getting. I have installed android studio(the latest version).

Comment: Have you installed flutter plugin on Android Studio

Comment: Yes, I have. I have created a new flutter app in AS as well, but flutter still isn't detecting Android Studio.

Comment: Not sure if this could be the problem, but is Android Studio on the PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Did You Try This:

> flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android
> Studio"